# Insert into a text file in an alphabetical order

Tags: shell

I have a text file like this:

```
'banana'                    => 'banana.exampl.com',
'banana.local'              => 'banana.exampl.com',
'banana-local.exampl.com' => 'banana.exampl.com',
'banana.exampl.com'       => 'banana.exampl.com',


'cat'                    => 'cat.exampl.com',
'cat.local'              => 'cat.exampl.com',
'cat-local.exampl.com' => 'cat.exampl.com',
'cat.exampl.com'   => 'cat.exampl.com',
```

Now I want to insert these lines into the text file

```
'beans'                    => 'beans.exampl.com',
'beans.local'              => 'beans.exampl.com',
'beans-local.exampl.com' => 'beans.exampl.com',
'beans.exampl.com'       => 'beans.exampl.com',
```

It should be entered alphabetically correct like this:

```
'banana'                    => 'banana.exampl.com',
'banana.local'              => 'banana.exampl.com',
'banana-local.exampl.com' => 'banana.exampl.com',
'banana.exampl.com'       => 'banana.exampl.com',


'beans'                    => 'beans.exampl.com',
'beans.local'              => 'beans.exampl.com',
'beans-local.exampl.com' => 'beans.exampl.com',
'beans.exampl.com'       => 'beans.exampl.com',


'cat'                    => 'cat.exampl.com',
'cat.local'              => 'cat.exampl.com',
'cat-local.exampl.com' => 'cat.exampl.com',
'cat.exampl.com'   => 'cat.exampl.com',
```

I was looking to use to sed but couldn't find anything that could help me insert in an alphabetically correct way.

Thanks

Comment: why not you try `sort` for that

Comment: Just append these new lines and then sort the file.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest, just sort.  Try putting your information in newfile and sorting that together with oldfile.

```
copy currentfile oldfile
sort newfile oldfile > currentfile
```

Comment: Thanks. After 'cat'                    => 'cat.exampl.com',
'cat.local'              => 'cat.exampl.com',
'cat-local.exampl.com' => 'cat.exampl.com',
'cat.exampl.com'   => 'cat.exampl.com', there is ");", how to insert before the curly braces. also sort is introducing ^z in all the lines. How to avoid that?